# Finding discontinuities points

Tags: calculus

> find discontinuities points of the function $f(x)=x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor$

I know that there is no limit $f(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ when $x\in \mathbb{N}$ Is it sufficient to say that therefore there are discontinuities points when $x\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The discontinuities are "from the left", as $lim_{x\to n-}(x-\lfloor x\rfloor) = 1 \ne f(n) = 0$, whereas approaching $n$ from the right, $lim_{x\to n+}(x-\lfloor x\rfloor) = 0$. You should also say that those are the only discontinuities. The question as you present it doesn't ask for reasons why, so I'm not sure if you're expected to give any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every open interval $(n,n+1)$, we have $\lfloor x\rfloor=n$, hence $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor=x-n$, which is well-known to be a continuous function.

Hence the only discontinuities are at $n$, as $\lim_{x\to n^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to n^{-}}(x-n+1)=1$ while $\lim_{x\to n^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to n^{+}}(x-n)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is discontinuous at all integral values. The graph is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If $p \in \Bbb{Z}$, then $p - \lfloor p \rfloor = 0$; but $\lim_{x \to p-}x - \lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ (You may want to prove this by $\varepsilon$-analysis). Hence every $p \in \Bbb{Z}$ is a point of discontinuity of $f$.

We claim that $f$ is continuous at every $p \in \Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Z}$; let $p \in \Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Z}$. If $x \in \Bbb{R}$, then
$$
|f(x) - f(p)| \leq |x-p| + |\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor p \rfloor|;
$$
if in addition $|x-p| < \min \{ p - \lfloor p \rfloor, \lceil p \rceil -p \} =: \delta$, then $|\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor p \rfloor | = 0$, implying that
$|x-p| + |\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor p \rfloor | = |x-p|$; given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|x-p| < \varepsilon$ if $|x-p| < \varepsilon$. Putting all things together, we conclude that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|f(x) - f(p)| < \varepsilon$ for $|x-p| < \min \{ \varepsilon, \delta \}$.